# How to construct an example of a function inside $H^{1/2}(S^1)\setminus \mathcal{A}(S^1)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces

In a lecture we proved that for all $s>\frac{1}{2}$, we have a continuous embedding $H^s(S^1)\hookrightarrow \mathcal{A}(S^1)$ where $S^1=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. we can embed the Sobolev space of regularity $s>\frac{1}{2}$ into the Wiener algebra on the circle. In the exercises we then saw that the logarithm provides an example of a function inside $H^s(S^1)$ for $s<\frac{1}{2}$ which isn't inside the Wiener algebra. But in the lecture it was also mentioned that $H^{1/2}(S^1)$ can't either be embedded into $\mathcal{A}(S^1)$. So I wondered: what is an example of a function inside $H^{1/2}(S^1)$ which is not in the Wiener algebra?

Comment: Just use the Fourier expansions $f(z)=\sum_k a_kz^k$. For $H^{1/2}$, the condition is $\sum_k |k||a_k|^2<+\infty$ and for the Wiener algebra it is $\sum_k |a_k|<+\infty$, so just find any sequence that satisfies the first condition but not the second one.

Comment: @fedja Hm yes I see what you are saying; $a_k=\frac{1}{|k|\log|k|}$ would work. But then it is not immediate that the function $f(x):=\sum_{|k|>1}a_ke^{2\pi i k}$ is actually well-defined, since the sum doesn't converge absolutely. How could one justify the existence of such a function?

Comment: The series definitely converges in $L^2$, doesn't it?